# Sonar runner can not find or load main class

Tags: project, sonarqube, runner

I have installed sonar and it works on `http://localhost:9000`

When I want to analyze a project using sonar runner (command from my project directory), I get the following error:

```
D:\eclipse_workspace\Project>sonar-runner.bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\sonar-runner-1.3\bin
Error: Could not find or load main class org.sonar.runner.Main
```

I'm working on Windows 7 and the property file is unchanged (derby database). How can I run sonar runner?

Comment: Sonar runner is not installed properly. I'm guessing it's the standard windows problem that you need to quote paths containing spaces characters.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try installing the Sonar Runner in a folder that does not contain spaces, this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this for a different reason. While my path was free of spaces, it had a 'fraction slash' (`'⁄'  // U+2044`) which caused the issue. Once I replaced it with an `-` things worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had non-latin (Japanese) folder names, which gave this error. Putting it in my `C:` root folder solved the issue.